# Creating a sparse matrix from numpy array

Tags: numpy

I need to create a matrix with values from a numpy array. The values should be distributed over the matrix lines according to an array of indices.

Like this:

```
>>> values
array([ 0.73620381,  0.61843002,  0.33604769,  0.72344274,  0.48943796])
>>> inds
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2])
>>> m = np.zeros((4, 5))
>>> for i, (index, value) in enumerate(zip(inds, values)):
        m[index, i] = value
>>> m
array([[ 0.73620381,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.61843002,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.33604769,  0.        ,  0.48943796],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.72344274,  0.        ]])
```

I'd like to know if there is a vectorized way to do it, i.e., without a loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2):

```
>>> values
array([ 0.73620381,  0.61843002,  0.33604769,  0.72344274,  0.48943796])
>>> inds
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2])
>>> mshape = (4,5)
>>> m = np.zeros(mshape)
>>> m[inds,np.arange(mshape[1])] = values
>>> m
array([[ 0.73620381,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.61843002,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.33604769,  0.        ,  0.48943796],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.72344274,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: [Looks in his command history to see why this didn't work for him, given that it was the first thing he tried.. realizes that he's an idiot.. deletes his answer and upvotes this.  IOW, a typical afternoon.]

Comment: @DSM, we've all been there. FWIW, your numpy/scipy answers are always stellar.

Answer (score 2):

Your `values` and `inds` arrays can be used as input to a `scipy.sparse` constructor (similar to sparse in Matlab).

```
from scipy import sparse
values = np.array([ 0.73620381,  0.61843002,  0.33604769,  0.72344274,  0.48943796])
inds=np.array([0,1,2,3,2])
index = np.arange(5)
m=sparse.csc_matrix((values,(inds,index)),shape=(4,5))
m.todense()  # produces a matrix or
m.toarray()
```