# convert list and list of lists to scipy sparse arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have a list or a list of lists (each list with the same size). How do I convert to a sparse vector or sparse matrix, respectively?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666521/creating-a-sparse-matrix-from-numpy-array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
In [5]: scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[1, 2], [3, 0]])
Out[5]:
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [6]: scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([1, 2])
Out[6]:
<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`scipy.sparse.whatever_matrix_type(your_data_structure)`. It's quite analogous to what you'd do to get a regular array. Note that there is no sparse vector or sparse ndarray class, only sparse matrices.

Comment: it's not quite qorking. can you possibly show an example?

Comment: scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(my_list_of_lists) does not work

Comment: @Bob: I did show an example. What exactly happens when it "does not work"? What do you get, and what did you expect to happen differently?