# Is there a Numpy function to map index of an array into a sparse vector?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a data structure like this:

- my source arrays are a sorted arrays like `[2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11]`
- I know a priori the max number of this array collection, in this case it’s 17

What I need to do is to build a sparse matrix with 17 rows (the max number mentioned above) and n cols where n is the number of arrays, and each column vector should contain a mapping of the index+1 of the source vector in position [value of the source vector’s element], and 0 when it’s not present. In the mentioned example the output vector should be `[0,1,2,3,4,0,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0,0,0,0]`.
Is there an efficient way to do that in numpy without having to loop through cols and rows which would have a dramatic computational cost?

Comment: NOt a `machine-learning` or `scikit-learn` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `scipy`). That said, have a look here: [Creating a sparse matrix from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666521/creating-a-sparse-matrix-from-numpy-array)

Comment: Your example isn't clear.  You tag `scipy`.  Is that because you want to use `scipy.sparse`?  Or are you just using `sparse` in the loose sense of an array with some 0s?

Comment: @hpaulj `scipy` tag was added by me in en edit, not by OP, as clearly stated in my 1st comment above

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

in_list = [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11]
in_list_len = len(in_list)
max_num = 17
a = sparse.csr_matrix((max_num, in_list_len), dtype=np.int)

for ind, val in enumerate(in_list):
    a[val, ind] = ind + 1
```

and

> ```
> Out[23]: 
> array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
> ```

Complexity is `O(len(in_list))`

Your desired output makes no sense, because you asked for a matrix but specified a list.
I am pretty sure this is what you wanted.

The closest would be

> ```
> a.data
> Out[18]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality appears to [exist in pandas](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/sparse.html):

```
matteos_sorted_arrays_with_nans = mateos_sorted_arrays
matteos_sorted_arrays[2:-2] = np.nan
sdf = pd.Series(pd.SparseArray(matteos_sorted_arrays_with_nans))
```

Without further particulars, I haven't the foggiest what to recommend as a next step, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `x` to assign consecutive numbers to elements of an array:

```
In [16]: x
Out[16]: array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [17]: arr = np.zeros(17,int)
In [18]: arr
Out[18]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [19]: arr[x-1] = np.arange(1,len(x)+1)
In [20]: arr
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```